# Notepad++ Search & Replace with Regular Expressions

Tags: notepad++, search, regex

I know its simple, but I can't get it to work...

I have a strings like

```
{span style="display:none"}123{/span} and 

{span style="display:none"}456{/span} and 

{span style="display:none"}789{/span}
```

in a file.

I want to remove all of these string.

So, I thought a simple regular expression replace in NotePad++ should be like

```
{span style="display:none"}[(.)]{/span}
```

but, this is not working.

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close

```
{span style="display:none"}(.*){/span}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

Now using {span style="display:none"}[0-9a-zA-Z_&-.  ]+{/span} in the search box!